# upload an image with other parameters as JSON type using javascript

Tags: javascript, upload

I have an object that contains parameters . I want to upload an image to a server but just using javascript.
how can I do that?

```
<input id="imgItem" type="file" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="title">
<input type="text" id="description">
<button onclick="handle();">
<script>
function handle(){
   var params={
   title:document.getElementById('title').value,
   desc: document.getElementById('description').value,
   img://i don't know what I must do,
   };
   postItem(params, function(data){
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   });

}
function postItem(param, callbackFunction){
   $.ajax({
   url:myUrl,
   data:param,
   type:'POST',
   contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   xhrFields:{withCredentials: false},
   success: function(response){
   callbackFunction(response);
   }
 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
var data = new FormData();

data.append('title', document.getElementById('title').value);
data.append('desc', document.getElementById('description').value);

$("input[type='file']").each(function (index) {
    try {
        data.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this)[0].files[0], $(this).attr('name'));
    } catch (ignore) {}
});

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
}).done(function () {
    //your code here
}).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    //your code here
}).always(function () {
    //your code here
});
```

Or use it as regular form submission and fill in title and description values in [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event.

Comment: it has an error that says:  
UNEXPECTED token ILLEGAL

Comment: I know that and I fixed it but the error still remained.